ERA5 Pressure Values on Theta Levels
How do I interpret the Pressure values in this dataset? I downloaded ERA5 Potential Vorticity and Pressure(Monthly means of Daily means, analysis, Potential Temperature levels). The pressure data doesn’t make sense to me. Please see the attached image. The potential vorticity data makes sense. It is a 2D grid with the same shape as the lats/lons. But the pressure data is 1D with a length that doesn’t match anything I can think of. Any advice? Thanks!

Download request:
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

c.retrieve("reanalysis-era5-complete", {
    "class": "ea",
    "date": "20200101/20200201/20200301/20200401/20200501/20200601/20200701/20200801/20200901/20201001/20201101/20201201/20210101/20210201/20210301/20210401/20210501/20210601/20210701/20210801/20210901/20211001/20211101/20211201/20220101/20220201/20220301/20220401/20220501/20220601/20220701/20220801/20220901/20221001/20221101/20221201/20230101/20230201/20230301/20230401/20230501/20230601/20230701/20230801/20230901/20231001/20231101/20231201/20240101/20240201/20240301/20240401/20240501/20240601/20240701/20240801",
    "expver": "1",
    "levelist": "265/275/285/300/315/320/330/350/370/395/430/475/530/600/700/850",
    "levtype": "pt",
    "param": "54.128/60.128",
    "stream": "moda",
    "type": "an"
}, "output")


including the API request would help

I have added my API request that I used to download the data.

So if you convert your grib file to netcdf like this
cdo -f nc4 copy test.grb test.nc4

and look at the header with ncdump
ncdump -h test.nc4

you will see that the PV field (var60) is retrieved on an unstructured reduced
Gaussian grid and the pressure field (var54) is a spectral field, that's why you have the zeros as these are the spectral coefficients.
float var54(time, lev, nsp, nc2) ;
    var54:table = 128 ;
    var54:CDI_grid_type = "spectral" ;
    var54:axis = "TZ--" ;
    var54:truncation = 639 ;
float var60(time, lev, rgrid) ;
    var60:table = 128 ;
    var60:CDI_grid_type = "gaussian_reduced" ;
    var60:CDI_grid_num_LPE = 320 ;
    var60:CDI_grid_latitudes = "lat" ;
    var60:CDI_grid_reduced_points = "reduced_points" ;

This makes conversion to a regular grid problematic with cdo, you can do this with eccodes though.
However, a far easier solution is to simply request a regular lat-lon grid in the original retrieval, and let MARS handle the interpolation for you.  You can do this with the keyword "grid", like this (I also use the format keyword to get the file directly as netcdf, but of course you can stay with grib if you prefer).
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

c.retrieve("reanalysis-era5-complete", {
    "class": "ea",
    "date": "20200101",
    "expver": "1",
    "levelist": "265/275/285/300/315/320/330/350/370/395/430/475/530/600/700/850",
    "levtype": "pt",
    "param": "54.128/60.128",
    "stream": "moda",
    "type": "an",
    "grid": "F128",
    "format":"netcdf"
}, "test2.nc")

This retrieves the data directly on a regular lat-lon grid.
My test2.nc file now has these dimensions:
longitude = 512 ;
latitude = 256 ;
theta = 16 ;

And here are my regular-gridded field headers for the two variables:
float pres(theta, latitude, longitude)
float pv(theta, latitude, longitude)

I used a low resolution 128 grid here, but you can select others.  See the WIKI for the grid options.

Wow! Thank you! I hadn't considered that the data would be exported in different coordinates for different parameters. I like the idea of adding the grid in the request instead of trying to convert the dataset.

IFS is still based on a spectral core (for the moment! This will change  ) :-)

410420 = 2 × 2 × 5 × 20521, so something like grbs[1].values.reshape((-1, 2)) could help.

Thanks for the help, but that still doesn't explain the values very well. The other variable (Potential Vortcity) (at grbs[2] for example) has a shape (640, 1280) or 819,200 grid points which I can't figure out how that maps to the pressure values. Nor can I figure out how to explain the pressure values themselves. Only the first value makes physical sense to be (972.8mb) in the example I posted, but what do all the other values mean? every other value is 0, and I guess the others are a deviation from the first?
